# Bootstrap navbar items flash different color on load

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, phoenix-framework

I'm using Bootstrap 5 and I've got a navbar.

I've changed `$primary` and `$secondary` colors and I set my navbar items to be white. Whenever I click on different navbar items it first flashes my primary color and then turns to white. Also that doesn't happen all the time as you can see from the gif below sometimes it flashes different shade of white which is probably the default from Bootstrap.

[image: navbar changing colors]

That only happens with Chrome and on Chrome I can see that the CSS file is not cached and it's fetched all the time. I don't see the same thing happen on Firefox because there the CSS file is cached.

I am not 100% it's because of the cache but I just wanted to mention. Maybe I'm doing something wrong with my `app.scss`.

```css
/* relevant snippet from my app.scss */

$primary: #161F6D;
$secondary: #00ABE1;
$font-family-base: 'Poppins', sans-serif;

@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

.navbar-dark {
  .navbar-nav {
    .nav-link {
      color: white;
    }
    .nav-link.active {
      color:  $primary;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Form your post _CSS file is not cached and it's fetched all the time_, How do you link to the CSS file? Do you always end **.css** with any random string? For example: `<link href=".../my.css?v=1234567">`.

Comment: No, I actually have something like `<link rel="stylesheet" href={Routes.static_path(@conn, "/css/app.css")}/>`

Comment: `Routes.static_path` is not normal JS, CSS. If you use something more please add them as tag. I have no idea what is `Routes.static_path` and where does it come from?

Comment: Sorry, that actually comes from Elixir Phoenix (web framework) so it's actually parsed to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">`.